# 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to convert some VB.net code into C# and having issues trying to convert this one line.

VB.NET

```
Dim myreg As Microsoft.Win32.Registry
```

I know it's a static so I can't create an instance but when I tried a VB.NET converter to C# the website gives me this:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry myreg = null;
```

And gives me an error message: 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

In the last part of the Function in VB.NET, myreg is used:

```
Finally
  myreg = Nothing
End Try
```

Here's the whole function:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
Imports MyLogger 'custom reference, not worried about this.

Private Function getRegistryString(ByVal sVal As String, Optional ByVal sKey As String = "") As String
    Dim myreg As Microsoft.Win32.Registry
    Dim s As String
    Try
        s = myreg.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sKey).GetValue(sVal)
    Catch ex As Exception
        l.EventLog(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
        Throw ex
    Finally
        myreg = Nothing
    End Try
    Return s
    s = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Are those the only references?  Can you provide more information as to how you are using the code?  Here is the page on the .NET Registry class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=vs.71%29

Comment: Where did you get the VB code from? It’s … weird, to say the *very* least.

Comment: yea it's a former coworkers code, lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.NET, there is no way to define a *shared* (static) class.  In C#, however, you can specify that a class is static.  When a class is static, it forces all its members to be static as well.  The compiler will give you an error if you try to declare a variable of a static type.

In VB, however, since there is no such thing as a shared class, it always allows you to declare a variable of any type, even though it's entirely pointless because the instance will have no members.

Instead of declaring a variable as type `Registry`, you need to change the code to simply use the `Registry` class name, itself.  Setting the variable to `Nothing` is meaningless because the variable never stores a reference to an object.  It's always `Nothing`.

Your function should read like this:

```vb
Private Function getRegistryString(ByVal sVal As String, Optional ByVal sKey As String = "") As String
    Dim s As String
    Try
        s = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sKey).GetValue(sVal)
    Catch ex As Exception
        l.EventLog(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return s
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

`Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is a static class so you cannot instantiate it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

Edit: Should have been a comment instead of an answer. I'm still new to this site sorry.

Comment: So in VB.NET it can be instantiated but in C# it can't? If that's the case is there anyway to convert "Finally   myreg = Nothing End Try" to C#?

Comment: @nhat `static` (`Shared` for methods in VB.NET) is more or less a hint for the compiler to prevent errors of that type. Your VB.NET code isn't really valid because there is no need to create an instance of a class with only static methods (then there is no need to "clear" the variable). `static` is translated in VB.NET simply to `NotInheritable` so even if you can create an instance of that type (because the compiler didn't emit a private constructor) it's pretty useless.